# Copy File to Directory Based on Flat File Data

Tags: ssis

As part of my SSIS package I am reading in a flat file. Based on the data in one of my imported columns, `LocationID`, I want to specify a destination for the file to be copied to. Again, this is just a flat file destination.

The `LocationID` will always be the same in each individual text file.

Should I be assigning the value to a variable, and then a path against each variable for example? Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably assign the variable as you describe. I would then use the property expression editor to dynamically define the destination. Or if LocationID = 1 then **destination1** else **destination2**.